# Laptop screen flashing

Tags: laptop, display, backlight

I've recently bought this laptop: NP305V5A-S03IT, with the new AMD A8 APU and a dedicated video card in crossfire.

Anyway, from time to time (I think once or twice in an hour), the display turns black for a fraction of second (couldn't say if the backlight or the entire screen, it's fast but I think the first).

I tried to connect an external screen (a TV to be exact), and for what I've seen it doesn't happen with that (but the screen does); so it might be a problem of the screen itself, I think.

Somebody has a better idea?

(I'm not sure about the title, maybe there is a better word for this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, if you recently bought it, it is under warranty, the best advice I could give is describe the problem to the place you bought it from, or to Samsung support and get it repaired. No reason to go poking around in the machine when this should rightfully be corrected by the manufacturer.

If I were to troubleshoot the issue on an out of warranty laptop, I would start by making sure the sleep button isn't sticking or defective. Then move to the inverter board and finally the LCD itself.

Comment: My aim was only to understand if it's a driver bug; since I'm at 1000km from where I've bought the laptop, and in a different country, I was trying to wait before sending it to the support centre...but I think it's the best choice

Comment: Almost certain it wouldn't be driver if its flashing black. If it were flashing colors, or if the screen were artifacting... MAYBE. But in this case, most likely not. Even if it was, if its under warranty, let them fix it.